# Drop div from top to bottom with repeat 5 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to drop animat div from top-bottom on repeat 5 times,
on 1st div drops top-bottom once it completed then again 2nd div top-bottom div drop and so on 5 times.

```js
var bodyHeight = $('#moving').height();
var footerOffsetTop = $('#moving').offset().top;
var topToBottom = bodyHeight - footerOffsetTop - $('#moving').outerHeight();

$("#moving").animate({
  top: topToBottom,
  delay: 3000,
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="moving"></div>
```

its all i could have done, but dont know how to make it on loop 5 times
 help

Comment: Your code snippet isn't correct. It's missing the HTML.

Comment: You are missing the html part of your code. Please add it in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want? Make a `for` loop to be ran 5 times, set a time out so that the animation is completed, then execute your code.

```
for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
        var footerOffsetTop = $('#moving').offset().top;
        var topToBottom = bodyHeight - footerOffsetTop - $('#moving').outerHeight();

        $("#moving").animate({
            top: topToBottom,
            delay: 3000,
        }, 3000);
    }, count*3000);
}
```

Comment: So you want to drop it down five times, then put it back up?

Comment: 1st drop then rest to top 2nd and 3rd so on.. its shouldnt go bakward

Comment: Sorry but you're not making any sense, please provide some CSS and HTML.

Comment: i have provided , it just 1 div tag ....well simply i dont want pendulum animation... what i want it just drop top-bottom 1st time and then 2nd it will start to drop from top-bottom again

Comment: I'm having huuuge issues with understand you.. If you don't want the div to be slided down, why are you using an aniamtion then?

Comment: me too, I don't make any idea what he really wants at all